# DOM not changing when navigating to a new page safari selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, safari, webdriver

I am using the safari web driver to open the login page of my site. I am able to access elements and successfully login. Once logged in the page the home page loads. However, i am unable to locate or click any elements on the page.
I have tried by id, by tag, by class and by xpath. all fail to return any elements.
the call fail with a WebDriverException with no message.
I have got all the elements on the page using //*. This gives me a list of elements when i print the class names i can see it still has the elements from the login page.
It looks like the DOM is not refreshing. I have tried to refresh it my self using driver.refresh and also sending the command+r keys but nothing is working.
Any help is mush appreciated
Page object function

```
    def get_study_cards(self) -> list[WebElement]:
        self.selenium_puppeteer.wait_for_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "study-card", 20)
        self.selenium_puppeteer.take_screenshot("{} {}".format(self._get_name(), "get study card"))
        study_list = self.selenium_puppeteer.driver.find_element_by_class_name("study-card")
        return study_list
```

login test function:

```
    def test_login(self):
        self._set_up_test_reporter(
            self.test_config.test_login.test_title, get_practitest_id_from_config_test_id_field(
                self.test_config.test_login.practitest_instance_id,
                self.consts.web_driver_helper
            )
        )
        log_debug(self._get_name(), self.consts.test_config.global_level.starting_log
                  .format(self.current_test_reporter.test_name))

        self.biomarker_actions.navigate_to_biomarker_portal()
        self.biomarker_actions.log_in_from_login_page()
        studies_list = self.biomarker_actions.studies_page.get_study_cards()
```

page html:

```
<div _ngcontent-c7="" class="study-card">
  <a _ngcontent-c7="" href="/studies/BP39295">
    <div _ngcontent-c7="" class="card">
      <div _ngcontent-c7="" class="card-image">
        <img _ngcontent-c7="" src="data:image/png;base64,i" style="background-color: rgb(192, 202, 51);">
        <!----><div _ngcontent-c7="" class="edit-study-layer">
          <button _ngcontent-c7="" class="material-icons x-small">edit</button>
        </div>
        <!----><div _ngcontent-c7="" class="del-study-layer">
          <button _ngcontent-c7="" class="material-icons x-small" tooltip="">delete</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div _ngcontent-c7="" class="card-content">
        <p _ngcontent-c7="" class="card-title" data-tooltip="SMART_PD_HV">
          SMART_PD_HV
        </p>
        <dl _ngcontent-c7="" class="details">
          <dt _ngcontent-c7="">Sites</dt>
          <dd _ngcontent-c7="">0</dd>
          <dt _ngcontent-c7="">Subjects</dt>
          <dd _ngcontent-c7="">0</dd>
          <dt _ngcontent-c7="">Last updated</dt>
          <!---->
          <!----><dd _ngcontent-c7="">-</dd>
        </dl>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Error received:
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:

I expect a list of the above web elements with the class name study-card
This works fine on chrome, firefox and edge,
when debugging i put a breakpoint before and after the call to find elements but it never gets to the one after the call to find elements.
Just goes to the next test then i see the above error with no message
I followed the call to Webdriver

```
def execute(self, driver_command, params=None):
```

and it gets the error here

```
 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
```

response is a 500 unknown error

Comment: Can you post the code for your test, web page, and error/expected result?

Comment: Add html code or link to site

Comment: Updated with code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  :-

```
driver.get(driver.current_url)
```

Comment: driver.current_url returns the URL its supposed to after login
test.studydash.io/studies